# Loading a config.json file at runtime in an angular application

Tags: angular, keycloak, angular-http-interceptors

I have a problem and I wanted to ask if someone might help me out there :)

In my application have a config.json file which contains some information depending on it's stages (e.g. dev, IN, Prod ...).

```
{
  "queryUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
  "commandUrl": "http://localhost:8282",
  "ssoUrl": "https:someurlcode",
  "ssoRealm": "someRealm",
  "ssoClient": "dev"
}
```

This file I wanted to exchange after the application is build since its different for the different stages. (This works fine in the Jenkins Build)

Now I have written a Keycloak Service, where I create the token:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// @ts-ignore
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
// @ts-ignore
import * as config from '../../../assets/config.json';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KeycloakService {

  private keycloakAuth: any;

  private ssoUrl: string;
  private ssoRealm: string;
  private ssoClient: string;

  constructor() {
      this.ssoUrl = config.ssoUrl;
      this.ssoRealm = config.ssoRealm;
      this.ssoClient = config.ssoClient;

  }

  init(): Promise<any> {
    console.log('init ' + this.ssoClient);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.keycloakAuth =  Keycloak({
        url: this.ssoUrl,
        realm: this.ssoRealm,
        clientId: this.ssoClient
      });
      this.keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })
          .then(() => {
            console.log('keycloak success');
            resolve();
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.log('keycloak error');
            reject();
          });
    });
  }
  getToken(): string {
    return this.keycloakAuth.token;
  }
}
```

As you may see I load the Json via an import statement. If I exchange the file now, it still uses the old file --> guess that's obvious since its taken at build time.

Next here is my http interceptor:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {KeycloakService} from './keycloak.service';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, retry} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

/**
 * Passes on the KeyCloak token
 */
@Injectable()
export class KeycloakInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private kcService: KeycloakService, private router: Router) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authToken = this.kcService.getToken() || '';
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken
            }
        });
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            retry(1),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.status !== undefined) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/error'], {queryParams: {errorCode: error.status}});
                } else {
                    return throwError(error);
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```

and also some insights from the app.module.ts

```
   {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: keycloakFactory,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: KeycloakInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }

....

export function keycloakFactory(keycloakService: KeycloakService) {
  return ()  => keycloakService.init();
}
```

I tried it a couple of times to load it in the init function etc. but always got an error like undefined etc...

Hope someone can help me...

Cheers Jack

Comment: import is not there to serve this use case. Use HTTP in a web application or the file system in a node application/build script.

Comment: True that's the actual problem, if I use http.get, the data won't be loaded before I need it in the interceptor

Comment: Then you need a non-intercepted request. Using a module mechanism to load the configuration just to bypass your interceptor is improper

Answer (score 1):

Configuration.js

```
window.securityConfiguration = {
  security: {
    "queryUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
    "commandUrl": "http://localhost:8282",
    "ssoUrl": "https:someurlcode",
    "ssoRealm": "someRealm",
    "ssoClient": "dev"
  }
};
```

Then in your application

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.keycloakAuth =  Keycloak({
    url: window.securityConfiguration.ssoUrl,
    realm: window.securityConfiguration.ssoRealm,
    clientId: window.securityConfiguration.ssoClient
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the Idea, but how will your realise that in Type Script ?

Comment: I don't do type script...

It's just the answer for your question above..

Maybe check how you can expose/re-use a global var in your application. Sorry I won't be able to help you in that part as I don't do Type script..

Comment: @JackJones all JavaScript is TypeScript.